# Кластер в Windows

Tags: windows, сеть, кластер

Слышал есть такая система как MPICH с помощью её вроде как можно сделать кластер например из двух ноутбуков с Windows, подскажите так ли это и как это сделать если возможно? Ничего толкового не нагуглил, вроде все под Линукс. Использую 2 ноутбука Windows 10x64 и 7x32 и соединение Ethernet.

Comment: А что ты там собрался запускать?

Comment: Игры в основном, ну что есть возможность сделать?

Comment: Только что вот наткнулся на информацию что MPICH2 в Windows вроде больше не поддерживается вместо неё есть MS-MPI

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что ты запараллелишь вычисления для игр и что это будет работать как надо. И накладные расходы большие и сетка нужна гигабитная и 32 битна наверняка надо будет менять на 64. Стоит попробовать только ради академического интереса.